# Windows 10 Cellular With LAN

Tags: networking, windows-10, cellular-internet

I have a system that relies on a cellular connection managed by Windows for internet access. An issue is coming up when a LAN connection is made to some local hardware. When connected locally the PC looses the internet connection, but windows still lists the cell network as connected. I have tried a few fixes including changing the network priority as described in the link below.

https://www.ghacks.net/2016/12/02/change-network-adapter-priorities-in-windows-10/

Are there any other settings I should be looking at or ways to manage the network? I have the version of Windows 10 at 1803

Comment: Did you manage solving this problem ? I'm having same issue

Answer (score 4):

Windows 10 always prefer ethernet over cellular, even if the ethernet connection has no route to the internet.
This behaviour can be modified since update [KB4284822](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4284822/windows-10-update-kb4284822) by adding the registry key:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WcmSvc\IgnoreNonRoutableEthernet = (DWORD) 0x1

Source: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-iotcore-docs/issues/343